# Linq group by and count - how do I add more columns?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following linq query

```
from c in AllContracts
group c.StatusId by c.StatusDescription
into g
select new {StatusDescription = g.Key, CountOf = g.Count()}
```

which returns

```
StatusDescription       CountOf
End date has passed     1
Suspended               1
Setup phase             2
Running                 7
```

However I would love to add the column StatusId into the results and also order by StatusId. I have googled around but I am stumped. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(from c in AllContracts
group c by new {c.StatusId, c.StatusDescription}
into g
select new {
    StatusId = g.Key.StatusId,
    StatusDescription = g.Key.StatusDescription,
    CountOf = g.Count()
}).OrderBy(item => item.StatusId)
```

Comment: Spot on, could not seem to find that example from Googling!

Comment: What did you search exactly? You can find this by googling "linq group by two fields" :-)

Comment: I kept coming across 101 LINQ Samples, but still could not see the light through the trees! :)